# middleware setting cors headers works with app.use() but not for specific route

Tags: node.js, express, cors, fetch, middleware

middleware:

```
const enableCors = (req, res, next) => {
  res.set({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://127.0.0.1:5500',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'content-type'
  });
  next();
};
//this works from postman as well as from browser
```

The above middleware works fine when added like this `app.use(enableCors);` but I want it to work with a specific route and I use it like follows:

```
app.post('/resource', enableCors, (req, res, next)=>{
    res.json({msg:'success'});
});
//this only works from postman
```

I am pretty sure this has to do with how pre-flight requests work because  when requested from postman it works either way. but when it's requested from the browser using fetch(), it only works with `app.use()`
this is the frontend's fetch request:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/resource', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ key:'value' })
})
.then(res => {
    console.log(res);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('something went wrong', err);
    });
```

what is preventing it from working with specific route when requested from browser?

Comment: You fetch using `POST` method but you listen on the server for `GET`.

Comment: Go look in the network tab in the chrome browser and watch the request from the browser.  See exactly what the browser is sending and getting back from your server.  It's possible that you've triggered an OPTIONS pre-flight request and your `app.use()` handles that, but your `app.get()` obviously only handles the GET request, not the OPTIONS request.  When in doubt, go look in the network tab and see exactly what is happening.

Comment: It all works in postman  because there's are no CORS restrictions in postman.  That is something the browser implements.  But, your question is really confusing because you show a POST request and an `app.get()` handler which is only for a GET request.

Comment: @jfriend00 edited Question but that app.get() was only here not in the running code.

Comment: So, did you look in the network tab and see what's happening?  We can't do that for you.

Comment: I did. as Jose Mato said, I need to respond with an app.options() route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS works when browser send an option header, so, try to add a new router like:

```
app.options('/resource', enableCors, (req, res) => res.send());
```

Postman is not affected by CORS because is not a browser.

Comment: worked great. I added `app.options(enableCors);` and kept the old `post()` without any middleware. It was a legitimate question. I don't know why it was downvoted.